# How to Remotely Invoke Applications (.exe file) with PowerShell with remote pc on windows?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute following command on remote server:
`Import.exe`. file resides on remote server and this command is completely working on remote server's command line. But when I try to execute it from local system its not showing any error but still not producing any output.

Here is the command :

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\\V11\\IMPORT.EXE" -ArgumentList "cutrite1620626276329","/AUTO","/OVERWRITE"
```

I have connected to remote pc using ssh command.

> Note : Both pc, mine and remote pc, are windows.

Comment: How is this related to java or spring?

Comment: We need to implement this in spring boot, that's why.

Comment: This command worked with Case-sensitive name of exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Start-Process` command will execute process on localhost. (More on that here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1)

What you want to do is invoke this command in PSRemoting session like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "COMPUTERNAME" -ScriptBlock { 
    #This command will be executed on machine COMPUTERNAME
    Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\\V11\\IMPORT.EXE" -ArgumentList "cutrite1620626276329","/AUTO","/OVERWRITE" 
};
```

There are several ways to access psremoting (you can read it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-5.1)